# Repeating steps in merge sort

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to dig into some algorithms and stuck with merge sorting. I mean it works but I am logging the steps of this algorithm and it seams that it repeats same steps for same subintervals many times. Is this correct and is this the way this algorithm works?

For example, I have an array:

```
new int[10] { 9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 8, 7, 6, 0 };
```

And this is algorithm(taken from here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/14068/merge-sorting-algorithm-in-C-Sharp.aspx):

```
static void MergeSort(int[] a, int start, int end)
{ 
    if (start != end)
    {
        int n = (start + end) / 2;

        MergeSort(a, 0, n);
        MergeSort(a, n + 1, end);

        MainMerge(a, start, (n + 1), end);
    }
}

static public void MainMerge(int[] numbers, int left, int mid, int right)
{
    t.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(left, right ));

    int[] temp = new int[25];
    int i, eol, num, pos;

    eol = (mid - 1);
    pos = left;
    num = (right - left + 1);

    while ((left <= eol) && (mid <= right))
    {
        if (numbers[left] <= numbers[mid])
            temp[pos++] = numbers[left++];
        else
            temp[pos++] = numbers[mid++];
    }

    while (left <= eol)
        temp[pos++] = numbers[left++];

    while (mid <= right)
        temp[pos++] = numbers[mid++];

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        numbers[right] = temp[right];
        right--;
    }
}
```

Here `t` is just a list of start-end tupples. So in the end I see in `t` that `MainMerge` function has been called for same values many times:

```
-       t   Count = 126 System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Tuple<int,int>>
+       [0] {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [1] {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [2] {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [3] {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [4] {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [5] {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [6] {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [7] {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [8] {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [9] {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [10]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [11]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [12]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [13]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [14]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [15]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [16]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [17]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [18]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [19]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [20]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [21]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [22]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [23]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [24]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [25]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [26]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [27]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [28]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [29]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [30]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [31]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [32]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [33]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [34]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [35]    {(0, 1)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [36]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [37]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [38]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [39]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [40]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [41]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [42]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [43]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [44]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [45]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [46]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [47]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [48]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [49]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [50]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [51]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [52]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [53]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [54]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [55]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [56]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [57]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [58]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [59]    {(0, 2)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [60]    {(0, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [61]    {(0, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [62]    {(0, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [63]    {(0, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [64]    {(0, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [65]    {(0, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [66]    {(0, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [67]    {(0, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [68]    {(0, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [69]    {(0, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [70]    {(0, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [71]    {(0, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [72]    {(0, 4)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [73]    {(0, 4)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [74]    {(0, 4)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [75]    {(0, 4)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [76]    {(0, 4)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [77]    {(0, 4)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [78]    {(0, 4)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [79]    {(0, 5)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [80]    {(0, 5)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [81]    {(0, 5)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [82]    {(0, 5)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [83]    {(0, 5)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [84]    {(0, 6)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [85]    {(0, 6)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [86]    {(0, 6)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [87]    {(0, 7)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [88]    {(0, 7)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [89]    {(0, 8)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [90]    {(0, 9)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [91]    {(2, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [92]    {(2, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [93]    {(2, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [94]    {(2, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [95]    {(2, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [96]    {(2, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [97]    {(2, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [98]    {(2, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [99]    {(2, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [100]   {(2, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [101]   {(2, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [102]   {(2, 3)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [103]   {(3, 4)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [104]   {(3, 4)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [105]   {(3, 4)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [106]   {(3, 4)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [107]   {(3, 4)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [108]   {(3, 4)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [109]   {(3, 4)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [110]   {(3, 5)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [111]   {(3, 5)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [112]   {(3, 5)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [113]   {(3, 5)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [114]   {(3, 5)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [115]   {(4, 6)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [116]   {(4, 6)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [117]   {(4, 6)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [118]   {(4, 7)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [119]   {(4, 7)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [120]   {(5, 8)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [121]   {(5, 9)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [122]   {(6, 7)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [123]   {(6, 7)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [124]   {(7, 8)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       [125]   {(8, 9)}    System.Tuple<int,int>
+       Raw View
```

For example `tupple 0-1` is repeated 35 times! 35 times just for sorting first 2 elements? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error in your implementation

Where you have:

```
static void MergeSort(int[] a, int start, int end)
{ 
    if (start != end)
    {
        int n = (start + end) / 2;

        MergeSort(a, 0, n);
        MergeSort(a, n + 1, end);

        MainMerge(a, start, (n + 1), end);
    }
}
```

you should have

```
static void MergeSort(int[] a, int start, int end)
{ 
    if (start != end)
    {
        int n = (start + end) / 2;

        MergeSort(a, start, n);         // <------------ HERE IS THE FIX
        MergeSort(a, n + 1, end);

        MainMerge(a, start, (n + 1), end);
    }
}
```

Right now you are going all the way back to the start of the whole array at every step.

Comment: Oh my God. Thank you for quick answer. Now it is corrected.